# Cardinality of the set of all Perfect sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, set-theory, cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

What is the cardinality of the set of all perfect sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Is it $2^{2^{\mathbb{N}}}$?

Comment: I don't understand why this question (which seems nontrivial) has been closed. The OP offers a possible answer, a clear indication than he thought about the problem. I vote for reopening this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $c$ that is cardianlity of $R$ as number of open sets in $R $ is this so number of closed sets is also this.

Comment: I guess you just need to prove that the number of perfect sets in $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be countable.

Comment: Number of closed intervals is greater than that..I skipped it .

Comment: @ArpanSadhukhan No, that would not suffice. You need to prove that it is at least $\mathfrak c$, which is not the same as showing that it is uncountable. Ronit's comment gives this lower bound.